# Primefaces open confirm dialog if the form is not fully filled

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hello I'm trying to solve this problem. Hope you can help me.

I have a question form with optionals question (textfields, checkbox, radiobuttons). I'm trying to open a confirm dialog ("There are some question not answered, are you sure you want to continue? YES/NO") just if there are question unfilled. I can OPEN de dialog to ask for confirmation. But I cant validate if the dialog has to be displayed or it have to be skipped.

```
           <h:form>
               <div class="col-xs-12 ctg-home-button center">
                    <p:commandButton
                        id="cancel-button"
                        actionListener="#{answerSurveyView.restart}"
                        immediate="true"
                        styleClass="btn btn-default"
                        title="#{propertiesBean.getProperty('answer.cancel')}"
                        value="#{propertiesBean.getProperty('answer.cancel')}"
                        />
                    <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
                    <p:commandButton
                        id="answer-button"
                        action="#{answerSurveyView.saveAnswers}"
                        styleClass="btn btn-default"
                        title="#{propertiesBean.getProperty('answer.send')}"
                        update="answer-form"
                        value="#{propertiesBean.getProperty('answer.send')}"
                        >
                        <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="#{propertiesBean.getProperty('answer.survey-confirmation')}" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </div>
                <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                    <p:commandButton value="#{propertiesBean.getProperty('answer.send')}" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                    <p:commandButton value="#{propertiesBean.getProperty('answer.close')}" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                </p:confirmDialog>
           </h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `rendered` attribute of your `confirmDialog` to indicate whether you want render it or not. Set to the `rendered` attribute a value returned from your view, indicating whether there are unasnwered questions or not.

Reload your `confirmDialog` each time the user asnwers a question by using an  `ajax` on event, calling a method on your view to recalculate the `unansweredQuestions` attribute; and the `update` attribute with your `confirmDialog` id as value, so you can set `rendered` to `false` once the last question is ansewered. 
For instance, if you were using a dropdown to give options for the answer, the code of the page might look like this:

```
   <div class="col-xs-12 ctg-home-button center">
       <p:commandButton ....
       .....
   </div>

   <p:selectOneMenu value="#{answerSurveyView.firstQuestionAnswer}">
       <p:ajax listener="#{dropdownView.onAnswerSelect}" update="myConfirm" />
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select option" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
       <f:selectItems value="#{answerSurveyView.firstQuestionAnswerOptions}" />
   </p:selectOneMenu>

   <p:confirmDialog id='myConfirm' rendered="#{answerSurveyView.unansweredQuestions}" global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
       <p:commandButton value="#{propertiesBean.getProperty('answer.send')}" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
       <p:commandButton value="#{propertiesBean.getProperty('answer.close')}" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
   </p:confirmDialog>
```

And the code in your view:

```
// declare  unansweredQuestions attribute and set it to false
private boolean unansweredQuestions = false;

// unansweredQuestions getter
public boolean getUnansweredQuestions() {
    return unansweredQuestions;
}

// call this method every time a question is answered
// to update the unansweredQuestions value
public void onAnswerSelect() {
    unansweredQuestions = foo(); //method returns true if there are questions left and false if not.
}
```